# импорт bash в python

Tags: python, bash

Код на bash парсит файл логката и в дальнейшем создаёт файлы с правилами сеполиси, в зависимости от того, что в логкате. (Возможно я криво пояснил суть..)
[Полный файл](https://gist.github.com/andrwgldmn/be90ae7aeff2bb7e3993ffc55fb4db35)

Входные данные:

```
I/auditd  (    1): type=1400 audit(0.0:3): avc: denied { module_request } for comm="init" kmod="fs-cpuset" scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=1
I/auditd  (    1): type=1400 audit(0.0:4): avc: denied { setattr } for comm="init" name="mmcblk0p1" dev="tmpfs" ino=10408 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tad_block_device:s0 tclass=blk_file permissive=1
```

Выходные:

Создаётся папка, а в ней файлы *.te, где * это имя в промежутке между scontext=u:r: и :s0, т.е init (в данном случае)
Содержание файла такое:

```
allow init kernel:system { module_request };
allow init tad_block_device:blk_file { setattr };
```

Как будет выглядеть кусок кода на bash:

```
#-----------------Permission settings-------------------
permissions_set(){
x_file_perms=(getattr execute execute_no_trans)
r_file_perms=(getattr open read ioctl lock)
w_file_perms=(open append write)
link_file_perms=(getattr link unlink rename)
create_file_perms=(create setattr rw_file_perms link_file_perms)
r_dir_perms=(open getattr read search ioctl)
w_dir_perms=(open search write add_name remove_name)
create_dir_perms=(create reparent rmdir setattr rw_dir_perms link_file_perms)

if [[ " ${x_file_perms[@]} " =~ "$SERVICE_PERM" ]]; then
    SERVICE_PERM_ARR="rwx_file_perms"
fi
if [[ " ${r_file_perms[@]} " =~ "$SERVICE_PERM" ]]; then
    SERVICE_PERM_ARR="rwx_file_perms"
fi
if [[ " ${w_file_perms[@]} " =~ "$SERVICE_PERM" ]]; then
    SERVICE_PERM_ARR="rwx_file_perms"
fi
if [[ " ${link_file_perms[@]} " =~ "$SERVICE_PERM" ]]; then
    SERVICE_PERM_ARR="link_file_perms"
fi
if [[ " ${create_file_perms[@]} " =~ "$SERVICE_PERM" ]]; then
    SERVICE_PERM_ARR="create_file_perms"
fi
if [[ " ${r_dir_perms[@]} " =~ "$SERVICE_PERM" ]]; then
    SERVICE_PERM_ARR="rw_dir_perms"
fi
if [[ " ${w_dir_perms[@]} " =~ "$SERVICE_PERM" ]]; then
    SERVICE_PERM_ARR="rw_dir_perms"
fi
if [[ " ${create_dir_perms[@]} " =~ "$SERVICE_PERM" ]]; then
    SERVICE_PERM_ARR="create_dir_perms"
fi
}
#--------------------------------------------------------

#--------------Getting attributes from log file--------------------------
while read LINE; do
read SERVICE_NAME < <(echo $LINE | grep -o "I [a-z,0-9,_, ]* : " | grep -o "[a-z0-9]*")
read SERVICE_PERM < <(echo $LINE | grep -o "{ [a-z_]* }" | grep -o "[a-z_]*")
read SERVICE_TYPE_CHECK < <(echo $LINE | grep -o "object_r:[a-z_]*:" | grep -o ":[a-z_]*:" | grep -o "[a-z]*")
read SERVICE_TYPE2 < <(echo $LINE | grep -o "tclass=[a-z_]* " | grep -o "=[a-z_]*" | grep -o "[a-z_]*")
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

в python? 
Моих познаний пока что хватает только на присвоение значений переменным и на простенькие циклы..  Буду рад любым подсказкам, спасибо.

Comment: Было бы неплохо добавить в вопрос описание словами того, что делает (должен делать) данный код...

Comment: В начале объявлены списки. Потом, похоже, происходит отбор в зависимости от входных данных. В общем, ничего сложного, если прочитать какую-то книжку по программированию на Bash.

Comment: @MaxU, обновил вопрос

Comment: Увеличивайте свои познания в bash и python чтением учебников, а уже потом возвращайтесь к решению этой задачи

Comment: @andreymal можете порекомендовать какие-то?

Comment: @AndrewGoldman, можете привести примеры входных и выходных данных?

Comment: @MaxU https://gist.github.com/andrwgldmn/a92645733726ffd5fac8ff03410478d3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основываясь на своих предыдущих вопросах и ответах ув. @MaxU предлагаю свой вариант.

```
import re
with open('log.txt') as input_file, open('allows.te', 'w') as output_file:
    text = input_file.read()
    pat = r"""avc:\s*denied\s*({\s*[^}]*\s*})\s+.*?scontext=u:r:([^:]*):s\d+.*?tcontext=.*?:(\w{2,}):s0.*?\s+tclass=([^\s:]*)\s+"""
    for what, scnt, tcnt, tc in re.findall(pat, text):
        output_file.write("allow {} {}:{} {} \n".format(scnt, tcnt, tc, what))
```

Вариант с requests конечно хорош, но в моём случае идёт обработка локального файла.

Comment: `requests` я использовал, т.к. у меня не было локального файла, а скачивать его вручную мне было лень... ;)

Comment: offtop: мне захотелось переписать тот парсер только потому что я сильно ленивое чтобы руками написать 2-3 строчки :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте парсить эти данные при помощи регулярных выражений:

```
import re

pat = r"""avc:\s*denied\s*({\s*[^}]*\s*})\s+.*?scontext=u:r:([^:]*):s\d+.*?tcontext=.*?:(\w{2,}):s0.*?\s+tclass=([^\s:]*)\s+"""

res = re.findall(pat, text)
```

получится следующий список кортежей:

```
In [71]: res
Out[71]:
[('{ module_request }', 'init', 'kernel', 'system'),
 ('{ setattr }', 'init', 'tad_block_device', 'blk_file')]
```

теперь можно легко построить интересующий вас файл:

```
In [72]: for what, scnt, tcnt, tc in re.findall(pat, text):
    ...:     #print(f"allow {scnt} {tcnt}:{tc} {what}")   # for Python 3.6+
    ...:     print("allow {} {}:{} {}".format(scnt, tcnt, tc, what))
    ...:
allow init kernel:system { module_request }
allow init tad_block_device:blk_file { setattr }
```

пример для [данных из другого вашего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/954695/211923):

```
In [73]: for what, scnt, tcnt, tc in re.findall(pat, data):
    ...:     print(f"allow {scnt} {tcnt}:{tc} {what}")
    ...:
allow system_server usb_config_prop:file { read }
allow system_server usb_config_prop:file { open }
allow system_server usb_config_prop:file { getattr }
```

Comment: print(f"allow {scnt} {tcnt}:{tc} {what}") = SyntaxError: invalid syntax
я пытался более громоздко: https://gist.github.com/andrwgldmn/f7012c94a74e7025125044e5c151badf но оно почему-то падало на tcls_w на выходе, при том что все остальные выводились нормально, но только одна одинаковая строка и с разными параметрами..

Comment: @AndrewGoldman, какая у вас версия Python? Я обновил ответ так чтобы он работал и для Python 2.x

Comment: На данный момент работаю с вторым питоном. Можете взглянуть на мой пример по ссылке? Что с ним не так? Ну кроме того что оно кривое

Answer (score 1):

Пример решения для [данного входного файла](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/andrwgldmn/842bb5e97e24f6ce55a5a031a75fcab2/raw/f9acfabb3b79f02d7ee9bd0af3511e432c5a8f7f/tad):

```
import re
import requests

url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/andrwgldmn/842bb5e97e24f6ce55a5a031a75fcab2/raw/f9acfabb3b79f02d7ee9bd0af3511e432c5a8f7f/tad'
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text

pat = r"""avc:\s*denied\s*({\s*[^}]*\s*})\s+.*?scontext=u:r:([^:]*):s\d+.*?tcontext=.*?:(\w{2,}):s0.*?\s+tclass=([^\s:]*)\s+"""

for what, scnt, tcnt, tc in re.findall(pat, data):
    print("allow {} {}:{} {}".format(scnt, tcnt, tc, what))
```

Результат:

```
allow init kernel:system { module_request }
allow init tad_block_device:blk_file { write }
allow init tad_block_device:blk_file { setattr }
allow tad rootfs:file { entrypoint }
allow tad rootfs:file { read }
allow init init:capability { sys_module }
allow init system_file:system { module_load }
allow toolbox toolbox:capability { mknod }
allow taimport system_file:file { entrypoint }
allow taimport property_socket:sock_file { write }
allow taimport init:unix_stream_socket { connectto }
allow toolbox toolbox:capability { mknod }
allow ueventd wmtWifi_device:chr_file { relabelto }
allow init system_file:file { execute_no_trans }
allow audioserver nvdata_file:dir { search }
allow audioserver nvdata_file:file { read }
allow audioserver nvdata_file:file { open }
allow audioserver nvdata_file:file { getattr }
allow audioserver nvdata_file:dir { search }
allow audioserver nvdata_file:dir { search }
allow audioserver nvdata_file:file { read }
allow audioserver nvdata_file:file { read }
allow audioserver nvdata_file:file { open }
allow audioserver nvdata_file:file { open }
allow audioserver nvdata_file:file { getattr }
allow audioserver nvdata_file:file { getattr }
allow mediacodec mtk_mjc_prop:file { read }
allow mediacodec mtk_mjc_prop:file { open }
allow mediacodec mtk_mjc_prop:file { getattr }
allow mediacodec property_socket:sock_file { write }
allow mediacodec property_socket:sock_file { write }
allow mediacodec init:unix_stream_socket { connectto }
allow mediacodec init:unix_stream_socket { connectto }
allow mediacodec default_prop:property_service { set }
allow mediacodec system_prop:property_service { set }
allow mediacodec debug_prop:property_service { set }
allow audioserver media_rw_data_file:dir { search }
allow audioserver media_rw_data_file:dir { search }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:dir { search }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:dir { search }
allow stp_dump3 media_rw_data_file:dir { search }
allow stp_dump3 media_rw_data_file:dir { search }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:dir { write }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:dir { write }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:dir { add_name }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:dir { add_name }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:file { create }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:file { create }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:file { read append open }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:file { read append open }
allow stp_dump3 media_rw_data_file:file { read append open }
allow stp_dump3 media_rw_data_file:file { read append open }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:file { getattr }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:file { getattr }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:dir { remove_name }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:dir { remove_name }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:file { unlink }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:file { unlink }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:dir { read }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:dir { read }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:dir { open }
allow stp_dump3 sdcardfs:dir { open }
allow stp_dump3 media_rw_data_file:dir { read open }
allow stp_dump3 media_rw_data_file:dir { read open }
allow sn sdcardfs:dir { search }
allow sn sdcardfs:dir { search }
allow sn media_rw_data_file:dir { search }
allow sn media_rw_data_file:dir { search }
allow sn media_rw_data_file:dir { read open }
allow sn media_rw_data_file:dir { read open }
allow sn sdcardfs:dir { search }
allow sn sdcardfs:dir { search }
allow sn media_rw_data_file:dir { search }
allow sn media_rw_data_file:dir { search }
allow sn media_rw_data_file:dir { read open }
allow sn media_rw_data_file:dir { read open }
```