# Копирование строк с условием

Tags: python

Есть файл с таким содержимым:

```
I/SystemServiceManager(  954): Starting com.android.server.usb.UsbService$Lifecycle
I/auditd  (  954): type=1400 audit(0.0:141): avc: denied { read } for comm="system_server" name="u:object_r:usb_config_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=2361 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:usb_config_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
I/auditd  (  954): type=1400 audit(0.0:142): avc: denied { open } for comm="system_server" path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:usb_config_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=2361 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:usb_config_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
I/auditd  (  954): type=1400 audit(0.0:143): avc: denied { getattr } for comm="system_server" path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:usb_config_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=2361 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:usb_config_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
D/UsbDeviceManager(  954): setEnabledFunctions functions=null, forceRestart=false
I/UsbDeviceManager(  954): Setting USB config to adb
D/UsbDeviceManager(  954): setUsbConfig(none)
I/ActivityManager(  954): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000100 cmp=com.android.settings/.CryptKeeper} from uid 0 on display 0
```

Нужно копировать в файл строки имеющие в себе `avc: denied`.
Насколько я понял логику сего процесса, необходимо сначала сделать поиск по файлу (я пробовал регулярными выражениями:

```
with open('log.txt') as input_file, open('allows.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    text = input_file.read()
    for prop in re.findall(': (.+?) {', text):
        newline = '{} \n'.format(prop)
        output_file.write(newline)
```

но это получается довольно криво, т.к проходят и другие строки без `avc: denied`), а затем сделать проверку, мол, если `avc: denied` в строке есть, то она полностью копируется в файл, только додуматься к этому я не смог. Я правильно понимаю принцип?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('log.txt') as input_file, open('allows.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.writelines(i for i in input_file if 'avc: denied' in i)
```

Answer (score 1):

я уже делал Вам

```
import re
with open('file.txt') as source, open('output.txt', 'a') as destination:
    www = source.read()
    for string in www.split('\n'):
        wert = "".join(re.findall('(^.*avc: denied.*$)',string))
        if wert:
            destination.write(wert+'\n')
```

Comment: Операторы +(плюс) описание| ^ и $ ---------Начало и конец строки| .   -----------Один любой символ, кроме новой строки \n|* -------------0 (ноль) и более вхождений шаблона слева